# Groovy-TestNG-Ant running error

Tags: ant, groovy, testng

I've faced with next problem.

Trying to create pilot test-project using Groovy, TestNG, ant.

If I run tests from my IDE (Eclipse) - all is ok.

But when I try run tests using ant - not easy for me problem. Could you help me?

build.xml is present below.

Compile target - pass ok, but on runTest target I see problem:

**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject"**

```
<project basedir="." default="runTest" name="Ant file for TestNG">
<property name="src" location="src" />
<property name="build" location="build" />
<property name="libs" location="lib" />

<path id="class.path">
    <pathelement location="${libs}/testng.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/testng.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${build}" />
</path>

<taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="lib/groovy-all.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/testng.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>

 <target name="runTest" depends="compile">

  <mkdir dir="testng_output"/><!-- Create the output directory. -->

  <testng outputdir="testng_output" classpathref="class.path"> 
    <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/> 
  </testng>

</target>

<target name="compile">  
    <delete dir="build"/>    
    <mkdir dir="build"/>

    <taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc" classpath="lib/groovy-all.jar"/>

    <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="./build">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="lib/groovy-all.jar"/>
            <pathelement path="lib/testng.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <javac source="1.7" target="1.7" debug="off" />
    </groovyc>   
</target>

</project>
```

And this is testng.xml

```
<suite name="My Test Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="My Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Adding lib/groovy-all.jar to class.path? (just a guess since I noticed testng.jar is duplicated as pathelement). In Eclipse it might reach the Groovy jar thanks to some eclipse var pointing to its location. So indeed one has to provide extra properties/parameters when running ant from the command line, sometimes. Cheers,